# Como faço para somar valores de tabelas diferentes?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Possuo duas tabelas (Custas e Receitas) onde preciso fazer um **sum** do campo que contem valores de cada uma delas, após fazer um cálculo (Saldo) apresentando o saldo das Receitas - Custas = Saldo.

Segue as informações das duas tabelas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: os campos que preciso fazer um sum são: valor_receita e valor_custas. Todos do tipo float

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Na verdade criei uma tabela só para isso.

Comment: criei uma tabela chamada saldoprocesso para fazer os joins, mas tenho dúvida se isso é necessário? e se dá certo fazendo isso também.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que você não precisa dessa outra tabela. Talvez uma view pode ser útil, depende da sua decisão.

Tente o SQL abaixo:

```
SELECT
    CUSTAS_SOMA,
    RECEITAS_SOMA,
    (RECEITAS_SOMA-CUSTAS_SOMA) AS SALDO
FROM (
    SELECT
        (SELECT SUM(valor_custas) FROM custas ) AS CUSTAS_SOMA,
        (SELECT SUM(valor_receitas) FROM receitas) AS RECEITAS_SOMA
) AS SOMAS
```

No codeigniter, você pode utilizar:

```
$result=$this->db->query("
    SELECT
        CUSTAS_SOMA,
        RECEITAS_SOMA,
        (RECEITAS_SOMA-CUSTAS_SOMA) AS SALDO
    FROM (
        SELECT
            (SELECT SUM(valor_custas) FROM custas ) AS CUSTAS_SOMA,
            (SELECT SUM(valor_receitas) FROM receitas) AS RECEITAS_SOMA
    ) AS SOMAS
"));

$S=$result->first_row();

echo "Custos: ".$S->CUSTAS_SOMA."<br />";
echo "Receitas: ".$S->RECEITAS_SOMA."<br />";
echo "Saldo: ".$S->SALDO;
```

Comment: como ficaria essa query no Codeigniter?

Comment: editei a resposta

Comment: no CI não está funcionando dessa maneira

Comment: @Ramiro testei a query aqui e funcionou. Quanto ao CodeIgniter, tenta trocar $S=$result->first_row(); por $S=$result->row(); Acho que a versão do CI pode mudar isso um pouco.